# Nmap & Ettercap don't give the same result for hosts on Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I need some clarifying about Nmap and Ettercap. I just run thru my home Wi-Fi network and realized one thing I don't understand.

When using Nmap, I can see all of my devices on the network, so I assume that works great. When I run Ettercap, it says 0 hosts on the network, which is weird because I know there are some.

I'm using Windows 8.1 with VirtualBox where Kali is installed. For Kali, I'm using TP-Link TL WN722N. I'm not able to find any advise about what could be wrong.

Comment: Do you have the Kali VM set to use the bridged network?

Comment: No, I'm using external wifi adapter, so it has own interface which is detected by Kali. When you set VirtualBox to bridged mode ntb takes motherboard wifi module which I don't want to use